# Local nuget package A is added into B, but B doesn't see it

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, .net-framework-version

2 projects: MyProj.A and MyProj.B.

MyProj.A is built as NuGet package and added to MyProj.B.

MyProj.A is examined with Nuget Package Explorer and I see all types inside but MyProj.B sees nothing, even MyProj.B itself.

**MyProj.A structure:**

MyProj.A.csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net452</TargetFrameworks>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

MyProj.A.nuspec:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyProj.A</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <authors>MyProj</authors>
    <owners>MyProj</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <copyright>Copyright @ 2023</copyright>
    <description>MyProj A.</description>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Class1.cs:

```
namespace MyProj.A
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int Prop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

NuGet Package Explorer view:

[image: NuGet Package Explorer]

MyProj.B view:

[image: MyProj.B]

Comment: Do you want to use nuspec file? You can add pack options in your csproj file. Either way, the nupkg file doesn't have your project's dll file in it, and needs to be in a specific directory.

Comment: @gunr2171, No, I've added A to B via "Manage NeGet Packages...". Do you mean I need to provide *.dll inside nugpk-file?

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/quickstart/create-and-publish-a-package-using-the-dotnet-cli.  NuGet doesn't work by putting source code in a nupkg. And you can't put compiled binaries in just any location either, it needs to match specific conventions.  But the tooling does everything for you, if you use the tooling.